# optimizing ruby on rails sql query for eager loading

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I have the following scenario of table strcuture:

```
a = table_a.includes(...{set of tables referenced, nested}...).where(key = (:key),:key => key_list).all

a.ref_tableB.ref_tableC.each do |x1| #ref tableB and C are part of includes for eager loading

      x2 = tableD.where('id1 = ? and id2 = ?',x1[:id],a[:id]) # Need to optimize this and eliminate where

      x2.each do |x3|
```

I am trying to make use of the fact that tableD can be referenced this way

```
   a.ref_tableB.ref_tableD.where('id1=?',x1[:id]) #this works but there is no decrease in the number of queries possible i need to eliminate the where clause
```

but I need to meet those conditions in the where. To summarize, I need a better way to represent the where condition so that I can use the eager loading association to decrease the number of queries

If somethings unclear would be glad to clarify it.